# Can I run my WebdriverIO tests on UFT Digital Lab from microfocus?

Tags: webdriver-io, hp-uft

I need to connect to "UFT Digital Lab" of Micro Focus - a cloud service just like SauceLabs or BrowserStack.

https://www.microfocus.com/en-us/products/uft-digital-lab/overview

I checked the page to create Custom Service already but still couldn't find the best way to add custom capabilities. Can anyone tell me what is the best way to do it?